# Filter grid in a view using dropdownlist and Viewmodel

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, filtering, viewmodel

I would like to filter data in a grid with dropdownlist from a viewmodel but I don't know how to do.
I thought to create controller like this: 
My controllers:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var missions = this.db.missions_supportmission
            .Include(m => m.organization_desk)
            .Include(m => m.organization_programme)
            .Select(x => new MissionsViewModel()
            {                   
                DeskIdSelected = x.organization_desk.name_en,
                ProgrammeIdSelected = x.organization_programme.name_en,
                DeskList = new SelectList(this.db.organization_desk.ToDictionary(b => b.desk_id, b => b.name_en), "Key", "Value"),
                ProgrammeList = new SelectList(this.db.organization_programme.ToDictionary(b => b.prog_id, b => b.name_en), "Key", "Value")
    });
```

In the viewmodel I have this:

```
public class MissionsViewModel
{
    public missions_supportmission missions_supportmission { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string DeskIdSelected { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProgrammeIdSelected { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CountryIdSelected { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string NatureIdSelected { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string DirectionIdSelected { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UnitIdSelected { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string TypeIdSelected { get; set; }

    public SelectList DeskList { get; set; }

    public SelectList ProgrammeList { get; set; }
    public SelectList TypeList { get; set; }
    public SelectList CountryList { get; set; }
    public SelectList NatureList { get; set; }
    public SelectList DirectionList { get; set; }
    public SelectList UnitList { get; set; }
}
```

My View(in dropdownlist, I used first viewbag, but I don't want to use it anymore. I want to use strongly-typed code)

```
@model IEnumerable<MissionsDF.Models.MissionsViewModel>
```

```
        
            
                Filtres
            

            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Missions", FormMethod.Get))
            {
                
                    Localisation
                    
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model, "Desk", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                        
                            @Html.DropDownList("SelectedDesk",
                            new SelectList(ViewBag.Listedesdesks, "Value", "Text", "ViewBag.SelectedDesk"),
                            "All", new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-control" })
                        
                    
                
            }
        

    
        Missions
        
            @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
        
        
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index"))
            {
                
                    
                        @Html.ActionLink("Pays", "Index",
                        new { SortOrder =ViewBag.ListorderPays,
                            /*SelectedDesk = ViewBag.ListorderPays,
                            SelectedProgramme = ViewBag.ListorderDate,*/
                        })
                    
                    
                        @Html.ActionLink("Date", "Index",
                        new { SortOrder = ViewBag.ListorderDate,
                            /*SelectedDesk = ViewBag.ListorderPays,
                            SelectedProgramme = ViewBag.ListorderDate,*/
                        })
                    
                    
                        Personne
                    
                    
                        Missions
                    
                    
                    
                
            }
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                
                    
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DeskIdSelected)
                    
                    
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProgrammeIdSelected)
                    
                
            }
```

When I debug my project I have the following error

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.'
```

I know where come from the errors but I don't know how to write my code in the controllers to have in my view at a time a grid and a dropdownlist to filter data using viewmodel.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you're not using AJAX, you'll need to modify your index function to accept parameters for each filter and then setup a form on your view that passes those parameters to the function. Given the number of parameters you seem to want, it can be a fair bit of work. It would also help to include your current view code.

Comment: In my view I use  `@model IEnumerable<MissionsDF.Models.MissionsViewModel>`

Comment: I am not pretty sure what exactly you want but as far I understand you looking for a table(grid) and a dropdown which will filter your grid, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it's true. And I want to do it using viewmodel.

Comment: Can you please add some cshtml code to exactly understand what it will looks like

Comment: The `DeskList` and `ProgrammeList` seems to be exist in wrong place. Take them out from the LINQ and assign it separately e.g. `missions.DeskList` & `missions.ProgrammeList`, or use `AsEnumerable()` to convert into LINQ to Objects model.

Comment: Hi, I tried to do it but I don't know how to do it. sorry I'm beginner. Do you have an example of code?

Comment: How can I assign separately `missions.DeskList & missions.ProgrammeList`? Or how can I use `AsEnumerable()`